# EF6 alpha Async Await on an Entity Stored Procedure / Function Import?

Tags: entity-framework, async-await, c#-5.0, entity-framework-6

I'd like to apply the new async await functionality to Stored Procedures / Function Imports imported in my Entity model, but have as yet been unable to with the EF6 alpha.

Is it yet possible in EF6 alpha2 (or the nightly build as of 20211) to call any of the new Async methods on an Entity Function Import (which calls a SQL Stored Procedure) that returns a collection of Complex Type? e.g.

```
private async Task<IList<Company>> getInfo (string id)
{
    using (CustomEntity context = new CustomEntity())
    {
        var query = await context.customStoredProcedure(id).ToListAsync();
        // ".ToListAsync()" method not available on above line

        // OR ALTERNATIVELY
        var query = await (from c in context.customStoredProcedure(id)
                           select new Company
                           {
                              Ident = c.id,
                              Name = c.name,
                              Country = c.country,
                              Sector = c.sector, 
                              etc. etc....
                           }).ToListAsync();
        // ".ToListAsync()" method or any "...Async" methods also not available this way

        return query;
    }
}
```

"ToListAsync", or any of the new async modified methods do not seem to be available to the above Entity Stored Procedure / Function Import; only the standard "ToList" or "AsNumerable" etc methods are available.

I followed this (http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Updating%20Applications%20to%20use%20EF6) to make sure the code is referencing the new EF6 dlls and not EF5, as well as updated the various using statements. Aside from above, everything builds correctly. (.NET Framework 4.5)

The only time I can see the async methods is if instead of only importing stored procedures from the DB, I also import a table--then when referencing that table via the Entity context as above (context.SomeTable), some of the async methods appear in intellisense.

I'd really like to start using the new async await functionality on multiple Stored Procedures prior to returning data as JSON, but have not been able to get it to work so far.

Am I doing something wrong? Is async functionality not possible on Entity stored procedure / function imports? Thanks for your advice.

Comment: What type does `context.customStoredProcedure(id)` statically have?

Comment: System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<customStoredProcedure_Result>

Comment: Did you ever get it working? I have the same issue with Stored Proc needing to be ASYNC.

Comment: I hate to ask this same question again... Do you remember how to fix it?

Comment: I ended up using Insight.Database, a micro ORM for .NET, instead. It had the async functionality for sprocs that I needed at the time. Haven't kept up to date recently with EF6...assuming still nothing in this regard?

Comment: @blueFish I'm new to this topic but it looks to me like async syc support is now available in EF6, since last year, 2019.  It is a pity then that converting from EF5 to EF6 causes so many breaking changes, sigh! REF. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/async-and-stored-procedures-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now this is by no means the best solution. I added an extension method so that I could call await on my stored procedures. In the newer releases of EF6.1+ we should see this officially implemented. Until then a dummy extension method does the job.

```
static async Task<List<T>> ToListAsync<T>(this ObjectResult<T> source)
{
    var list = new List<T>();
    await Task.Run(() => list.AddRange(source.ToList()));
    return list;
}
```

If you reflect version 6 of EF you will see that `ObjectResult<T>` actually implements `IDbAsyncEnumerable<T>, IDbAsyncEnumerable`. And the method for `ToListAsync<T>(this IDbAsyncEnumerable<T> source)` should be able to wire it up the same as a LINQ query.

**Edit**
When the ObjectResult is empty null is returned. You could add `if (source == null) return new List<T>();` if you want to return an empty List instead of null.

Comment: Spawning a new thread with `Task.Run` just so you can "await" a method completely defeats the purpose of async/await. You released your primary thread by awaiting but then you just spawned a new thread. Your performance will actually be worse when you factor in the overhead for spawning this new thread and then finally resuming on the primary when the one you spawned completes.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but I felt I should share. You should use APM then wrap the synchronous calls in a Task.

Example:

```
//declare the delegate
private delegate MyResult MySPDelegate();

// declare the synchronous method
private MyResult MySP()
{
    // do work...
}
```

Then wrap the synchronous method in a Task:

```
// wraps the method in a task and returns the task.
public Task<MyResult> MySPAsync()
{
    MySPDelegate caller = new MySPDelegate(MySP);
    return Task.Factory.FromAsync(caller.BeginInvoke, caller.EndInvoke, null);
}
```

Call the async method when you want to execute:

```
var MyResult = await MySPAsync();
```

You can use up to three (3) parameters in the methods. Best practice is if you use more than three parameters; you should pass in a class.