# Async Await Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, asynchronous, entity-framework-6

I am using entity framework and am hoping of a way to await a result set from a stored procedure.

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<FixturesQueryPM>> LoadFixtures()
    {
        try
        {
           using (var db = new FordAviationEntities())
           {
               DateTime preDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-50);

                var obs = new ObservableCollection<FixturesQueryPM>();

                Mapper.CreateMap<DATA_GetFixtureList_Result, PM.FixturesQueryPM>();
                var rec = db.DATA_GetFixtureList(50);

                if (rec != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in rec)
                    {
                        FixturesQueryPM newRec = Mapper.Map<Model.DATA_GetFixtureList_Result, PM.FixturesQueryPM>(item);

                        obs.Add(newRec);
                    }
                    return obs;
                }
                return null;
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", ex.Message, Environment.NewLine, ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.ToString() : ""));
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Is this possible with SP's?
Thanks Scott

Comment: You'll need some asynchronous method in your Mapper

Comment: This is what you something looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15051375/ef6-alpha-async-await-on-an-entity-stored-procedure-function-import

Comment: thks. how would I implement the extension method? I have it in code but raising the toListAsync isn;t working. var rec = db.DATA_GetFixtureList(5)

Comment: I added it as a method. But it still blocks the thread on startup.
var rec = await ToListAsync(db.DATA_GetFixtureList(5));
Will look into tomorrow. thanks.