# Asynchronous methods not available for ObjectResult<T>

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn159793(v=vs.113).aspx) for EF6, ObjectResult implements IDbAsyncEnumerable`<T>`, IDbAsyncEnumerable - which should mean it implements asynchronous methods such as ObjectResult`<T>`.**ToListAsync()**, right?

However, I'm not seeing that as a possible method in Visual Studio when calling a stored procedure like this:

```
public async Task<List<MyObject>> GetResultFromMyStoredProcedure(string foo, string bar)
{
    return await context.My_Stored_Procedure(foo, bar).ToListAsync();
}
```

But calling the stored procedure as a query does seem to work:

```
public async Task<List<MyObject>> GetResultFromMyStoredProcedure(string foo, string bar)
{
    var fooParam = new SqlParameter("@foo", foo);
    var barParam = new SqlParameter("@bar", bar);
    return await context.Database.SqlQuery<T>("My_Stored_Procedure @foo, @bar", fooParam, barParam).ToListAsync();
}
```

I've made sure my project is referencing the correct EF dll (6.1.3) - using NuGet. What am I missing?

Comment: So what exact error message do you get?

Comment: ObjectResult<T> does not contain a definition for "ToListAsync".

Comment: So which exact `ToListAsync` method are you expecting it to use? It's not part of `IDbAsyncEnumerable<T>`, so presumably you're expecting an extension method... do you have the documentation for that method?

Comment: I think I was reading documentation for a nightly EF6 build and saw that this method was implemented, but it doesn't appear to be. I was hoping for a shortcut to make an existing web application asynchronous without having to change too much (it is a very large application). I guess I'll be doing it the second way as listed above.

Comment: I suspect there *is* a way of doing it - but you need to find the appropriate `ToListAsync` extension method, and make sure you have the right using directive.

Comment: Indeed -  someone has asked / answered with an example, but as a commented responded below this isn't a great way of implementing it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15051375/ef6-alpha-async-await-on-an-entity-stored-procedure-function-import

Comment: @JonSkeet there is one, but it's `internal`. I've decompiled and extracted it to my answer below. Hope I'm not breaking any reverse-engineering laws or something :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Update

Since you can't just convert to Queryable, I've decompiled the internal methods that EF uses for `IDbAsyncEnumerable` and made this extension method (out of the microsoft decompiled sources, so it should be as good as it gets):

```
public static Task<List<T>> ToListAsync<T>(this IDbAsyncEnumerable<T> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<List<T>> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<List<T>>();
    List<T> list = new List<T>();
    ForEachAsync<T>(source.GetAsyncEnumerator(), new Action<T>(list.Add), cancellationToken).ContinueWith((Action<Task>)(t =>
    {
        if (t.IsFaulted)
            tcs.TrySetException((IEnumerable<Exception>)t.Exception.InnerExceptions);
        else if (t.IsCanceled)
            tcs.TrySetCanceled();
        else
            tcs.TrySetResult(list);
    }), TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
    return tcs.Task;
}

private static async Task ForEachAsync<T>(IDbAsyncEnumerator<T> enumerator, Action<T> action, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    using (enumerator)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        if (await System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.WithCurrentCulture<bool>(enumerator.MoveNextAsync(cancellationToken)))
        {
            Task<bool> moveNextTask;
            do
            {
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                T current = enumerator.Current;
                moveNextTask = enumerator.MoveNextAsync(cancellationToken);
                action(current);
            }
            while (await System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.WithCurrentCulture<bool>(moveNextTask));
        }
    }
}
```

And you can have an overload without `CancellationToken` like:

```
public static Task<List<T>> ToListAsync<T>(this IDbAsyncEnumerable<T> source)
{
   return ToListAsync<T>(source, CancellationToken.None);
}
```

## Old answer (*not working*)

Not sure if I'm getting the right grip of the question, but can't you simply do this?

```
return await context.My_Stored_Procedure(foo, bar).AsQueryable().ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Unfortunately no; this was one of the first things I had tried. It compiles fine, but there is a run time error.

Comment: Forgot to show the exception: Message = "The source IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncEnumerable<T>. Only sources that implement IDbAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.

Comment: I've extracted (and slightly modified) the extensions method from the decompiled sources. It at very least compiles for me... don't have any mapped stored procedure at hand to test it. Please test it, should be quick :-)

Comment: Looks like it is working! I give it a few tests while pulling a few sprocs at the same time and see what results I get. Thanks! (updates coming)

Comment: Well, it works as expected - methods are called asynchronously and I see a massive improvement in performance! I wonder why the EF folks decided to make this a private set of methods...